# Visual Studio 2012 Design view out of sync

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I'm on the split view of Visual Studio 2012 and I make some changes on the Code window, the design window does not show the changes and instead gives me this message "Design view is out of sync with Code view. Click here to synchronize views".

Screenshot: http://s7.postimg.org/oxwnggeih/123.jpg

Is there a way configure Visual Studio to have Design view seamlessly updated as I write code?